# Create a File in a folder

Tags: java, io

In Java, I have a `File` object representing a folder:

```
String folderName = "/home/vektor/folder";
File folder = new File(folderName);
```

Now I want to create another `File` representing a file in this folder. I want to avoid doing a string concatenation like this:

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
File file = new File(folderName + "/" + fileName);
```

Because if I go deeper in creating this structure, I will come up with something like this:

```
File deepFile = new File(folderName + "/" + anotherFolderName + ... + "/" + fileName);
```

I would instead like to do something like

```
File betterFile = folder.createUnder(fileName);
```

Or even:

```
File otherFile = SomeFileUtils.createFileInFolder(folder, fileName);
```

Do you know of such solution?

> Note: It's quite OK to use "/" because Java will translate it to "\" for Windows, but it is not clean - I should use something like `"file.separator"` from `System.getProperties()`.

Comment: Note: If you're using Java SE 7, it's recommended to use the new File API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Javadoc for File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and you will see that the constructor takes a `File` object as parent.

Use the following form:

```
File deepFile = new File(folder, fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
String folderName = 
String fileName = 

File under = new File(folderName, fileName);
```

or

```
File folderFile = 
String fileName = 

File under = new File(folderFile, fileName);
```

simple as that ;)

Comment: This does not help me in case I am creating a deeper structure of folders. I really need the `folderName` to come from an existing `File` object. And `new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), fileName)` is just too ugly :) There has to be something nicer.

Comment: @maba You are right. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.